# Toolbar behind status bar

Tags: android, toolbar, material-design

I had a problem with toolbar and status bar. I change the app styles to AppCompat. My styles are:

for values/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primario_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primario_500</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>
```

for values-v21/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.BaseGps">
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

My problem is that half the toolbar appears behind status bar. In the next image you can see what happens.[image]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: change to `<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>`

Comment: I`ll try it but toolbar continue behind the status bar @Budius

Comment: well.. for sure it's one of those: `android:windowTranslucentStatus`, `android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds` or `windowActionModeOverlay` it's just a matter of testing and finding out.

Comment: Yes. With <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item> work fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is apply the item

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
```

in the styles.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like these answers. Just because with Material design a Navigation Drawer should overlap the toolbar and have a translucent status bar so long as the API level supports it.

If you want the toolbar to fit properly and have a translucent status bar then you just need these items in your style.

```
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Comment: That's right, but not enough. Probably `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` or `false` should be applied to some tags in layouts.