# How to adjust height of toolbar in lollipop devices in android

Tags: android

I am using toolbar in my app. Toolbar's height can be adjusted correctly in pre-lollipop devices, but toolbar is getting cut from the bottom in lollipop devices means not showing completely. Please help me.

Xml code for toolbar is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawerMainActivity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/containerView">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/save"
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>


</FrameLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="217dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="left" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using AppCompat? Then change the attribute for height to:

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

And set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` on your FrameLayout.

Comment: What i should use for height?

Comment: Your attribute for toolbar height. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem but now status bar color has changed

Comment: What do you mean by changed? From red to green or is there just an overlay? Then this is expected behavior and depends on the device. Feel free to upvote/accept the answer ;)

Comment: Is this orange what you set as colorPrimary? Did you removed `fitSystemWindows` from the toolbar? Did you override the windowBackground on your theme?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92355/discussion-between-dev-kumar-and-thomas-r).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution here:

[Toolbar behind status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133552/toolbar-behind-status-bar)

Hope it helps you!! :)

Comment: In your styles are all the item I mentioned? In this case, you should remove the android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" in your toolbar.... to aply your own style.